# Cannot register on commandlinefu with Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

> Cannot Complete Login
>
> Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

Login page: http://www.commandlinefu.com/users/openid

Comment: Seems to work with the URL declared as ''openid2.local_id'' in your openid profile